# Connecting HDFS with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hadoop, visual-studio-2013

I have an asp.net application running on Visual Studio in Windows; my data is on Hadoop on Linux.  How do I connect these?  Is there any web service on Hadoop?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please ask questions related to code.

Comment: Fixed grammar; tightened wording.

Answer (score 0):

You may install hive and query through hive.

> Use the `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection` class with the Hive ODBC driver to query Hive tables in the HDInsight cluster.

Source: [Using the Microsoft Hive ODBC Driver in a .NET client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749834.aspx)

Reference: [Hadoop or Big Data for Microsoft .NET programmers](http://forums.asp.net/t/1938196.aspx?Hadoop+or+Big+Data+for+Microsoft+NET+programmers)  and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt147240.aspx)